# How can I get Playwright to use Apple Silicon instead of Intel Chrome on an M1 Mac device?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, e2e-testing, playwright

I recently switched from an old lower power Mac Mini to a new Mac Studio with M1 max chip.

Suddenly my Playwright e2e tests started running really slowly.

When I run in debug mode, I can see that the page I am testing takes ~15 seconds to appear in the browser. On my old intel Mac Mini the page loads in a 1-2 seconds.

I ran the tests in debug mode and checked the version of Chrome, it said it was using the translated Intel version of Chrome instead of the arm64 (Apple Silicon) version. When I run Chrome in the Apps list, it runs the arm64 version.

When I installed Chrome, I installed the universal version.

Is there anyway to force Playwright to use the arm64 version? I'm wondering if this is the cause of the tests loading slowly.

Answer (score -1):

When you setup a new M1 Mac it gives you the option to copy your apps and data from your old device.

If you do this, I'd recommend going through and reinstalling the arm64 versions of each app.

In my case, I had the Intel nvm/NodeJS/npm installed. Running Playwright in Intel NodeJS was launching the Intel version from universal Chrome.

I installed arm64 NVM/NodeJS/NPM and then reinstalled Playwright and now it is opening the arm64 version of Chrome. This eliminated the 10-15 second loading cost on each test.

My Jest unit tests are also running twice as fast now.

If you want to see which version of an app you have installed, checkout the instructions in this article:

https://appletoolbox.com/intel-or-arm/